# ValueError: ['path'] when installing pyfim

Tags: c++, python-3.x, compiler-errors, installation, environment-variables

I am running a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine with Python 3.4.  I am trying to install a frequent pattern mining package for python called pyfim (or fim).  I have downloaded the .tar.gz and unzipped the contents.  Now I'm trying to install the package from these source files.  The instructions tell me to just type

```
python setup_fim.py install
```

Which is pretty normal.  When I run that command I get the following output.  It seems like there is an issue with my path variables and maybe my compiler???  I've been struggling with different installs of C compilers lately.  Can anyone out there help me figure out what's going wrong here?

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'fim' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']
```

Comment: I tried uninstalling all of my C compilers and then just installing a basic C-compiler (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 version 10.0.30319 with .Net Framework 4) and I'm still getting the same path error.  Any other ideas out there so something to try?  What should I be adding to my path?

Comment: I've looked at the source code for mscvcompiler.py that is throwing the error and done some debugging.  I found that the problem was that while the qurey_vcvarsall function was doing checks for required environment variables it only found one environment variable, "path".  It appears that the other required environment variables required ("include", "lib", and "libpath") are missing on my system.  I'm assuming these are environment variables that help the compiler do it's job.  Is there a way to just manually create these variables and point them to the right files/folders?

Comment: Question from @mynameisalexey :: Excuse me, did you fix it somehow? If yes, please let me know how? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I asked this question I was trying to build from source on a Windows machine.  With more experience I've found that the cleanest way to get this working on a Windows machine would be to use (Ana/Mini)conda to install `pyfim` with conda-forge.  The environment.yml file would look something like this:

```
name: pyfim_env
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - pandas<1.0
  - pip
  - python>=3.6,<3.7
  - pyfim
  - pip:
    - peakutils
    - tqdm
```

Open a command terminal, navigate to the location of the environment.yml file and then type `conda env create -f environment.yml` to build this environment.